# Multiple classes open, close only one

Tags: html, css

I used 2 classes in a div but want to close one of them first and close the other a little later in the code, is there any possible way? Facebook was just an example.

```css
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="title titleborder">Dank nasty title</div class="title">
  <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a></div class="titleborder">
 </header>
</body>
```

Comment: There is no need to "close" css classes like html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use classes in closing HTML tags. Use a `span`tag for the inner class:
(the CSS is just a random example to see the actual outcome of the different classes)

```css
.titleborder {
  border: 2px solid red;
  }
.title {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="titleborder"><span class="title">Dank nasty title</span>
  <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a></div>
 </header>
</body>
```